# With awk: print third column of line with "igroup" string, but only if all the next lines until the next "igroup" have the "not logged in" string

Tags: awk

Using input like this example

```
Igroup Name: asdfgsrhqms103
00:00:00:00:00:00:3f:30 (not logged in)
00:00:00:00:00:00:3f:32 (not logged in)
Igroup Name: asdfgs012
00:00:00:00:00:00:53:20 (logged in)
00:00:00:00:00:00:fb:1a (logged in)
Igroup Name: asdfgs013
00:00:00:00:00:00:52:98 (not logged in)
00:00:00:00:00:00:fa:ec (logged in)
00:00:00:00:00:00:fb:1c (logged in)
```

The only valid output would be `asdfgsrhqms103` (third column in the Igroup line), as it's the only one that has both lines `not logged in` before the next `Igroup`.
The number of lines may vary between each `Igroup`.

Tried chatgpt and bard :D

Comment: please update the question with the code you've tried as well as the (wrong) output generated by said code

Comment: could a line have a label *other than* `not logged in` or `logged in`? will all `Igroups` have at least one `(not) logged in` entry?  please update the question with these additional details, and if the answer is 'yes' to either question then also update the sample input and explain if/how that line should be counted;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gawk '/^Igroup/{ if(nli!=0 && li==0){ print g }; 
                 g=$3; nli=0; li=0; }
      /\(not logged in\)/{ nli++}
      /\(logged in\)/{ li++}
      END{ if(nli!=0 && li==0){ print g}
      ' input
```

- When input starts with `Igroup`

  - if `nli` is not equal to zero and `li` is equal to zero, print `g`
  - assign the value of the 3th column to `g` (`g=$3`), and reset the counters.
- When line contains `(not logged in)` add 1 to `nli`
- When line contains `(logged in)` add 1 to `li`

Comment: What if the last one (not followed by another line starting with "Igroup") had all "not logged in"?

Comment: Tks a lot Luuk!

Comment: @IceCreamToucan: Added the line `END{....}` to solve that 'problem'. 

Answer (score 0):

If *Igroup Name* is matched check if `x == y-1`, where `x` is the number of lines that matched *not logged in* and `y-1` is the number of lines in the block without the *Igroup Name* line. This assumes that everything but *not logged in* is criteria to not match.

```
% awk '/not logged in/{x++}
       {y++}
       /Igroup Name/{
         if(x != "" && x == y-1){print d3}
         d3=$3; y=0; x=0
       }
       END{
         if(x == y-1){print d3, x, y-1}
  }' file
asdfgsrhqms103
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution in [TXR](https://nongnu.org/txr):

Note the absence of any explicit state. The only variables that occur in the code are just pattern matching bindings which are never modified.

```
$ txr loggedin.txr data
asdfgsrhqms103
```

Code:

```
@(repeat)
Igroup Name: @name
@  (collect)
@nil (@status)
@  (until)
Igroup Name: @nil
@  (end)
@  (require (not (find "logged in" status)))
@  (do (put-line name))
@(end)
```

Colored by syntax highlighting:

[image: With syntax highlighting in Vim]